# Im doing a calculator in c and errors pop up when I try to run it

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error

Heres the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main () {
    int op,a,b;

    printf("***Welcome to the calculatron***\n\n");

    do{
        printf("choose an operation\n\n");
        print(" 1 : Addition\n 2: Substraction\n 3: Multiplication\n 4: Division");
        scanf("%d",&op)
    }while((op != 1 && (op != 2) && (op != 3) && (op != 4));

    printf("Type the first number");
    scanf("%d",&op)
    printf("Type the second number");
    scanf("%d",&op);


    switch(op)
    case 1:
        printf("You have chosen the Addition\n");
        printf("%d + %d = %d",a,b,a+b);
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("You have chosen the Substraction\n");
        printf("%d + %d = %d",a,b,a-b);
        break;

    case 3:
        printf("You have chosen the Multiplication\n");
        printf("%d + %d = %d",a,b,a*b);
        break;

    case 4:
        printf("You have chosen the Division\n");
        printf("%d + %d = %d",a,b,a/b);
        break;
     }
```

The errors

`expected " ; " before " } " token and expected " ) " before " ; " token are in lines 13 and 41`

I don't know what to do, please help.

Comment: the includes are the following: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

Comment: `void main()` is an invalid signature, invoking UB.

Comment: Two of the `scanf` calls are written without a terminating `;`...

Comment: scanf is missing a semi colon. Usually the error tells you exactly whats wrong.

Comment: `switch` block should be enclosed in braces.

Comment: How about learn the syntax properly? Trial and error is a really bad idea in C. What about the error messages don't you understand **specifically**? They could hardly be more clear.

Comment: You are not trying to _run_ the program, you are trying to _compile_ it.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a semi-colon after scanf:

```
 printf("Type the first number");
    scanf("%d",&op);
```

Also you're missing opening parenthesis of switch case:

```
  switch(op)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your program.

For starters function main without parameters should be declared in C like

```
int main( void )
{
    //...
}
```

You forgot to place semicolons in statements with `scanf` as for example in this code block

```
do{
    printf("choose an operation\n\n");
    print(" 1 : Addition\n 2: Substraction\n 3: Multiplication\n 4: Division");
    scanf("%d",&op)
    // must be scanf( "%d, &op );
}while((op != 1 && (op != 2) && (op != 3) && (op != 4));
```

The condition in the while can be written simpler like

```
}while (op < 1 || op > 4 );
```

It is better to declare the variable `op` as having type `unsigned int` if it is supposed that it should not accept negative values.

In these statements

```
printf("Type the first number");
scanf("%d",&op)
printf("Type the second number");
scanf("%d",&op);
```

you have to enter values for variables `a` and `b` instead of the variable `op`.

```
printf("Type the first number");
scanf("%d",&a)
printf("Type the second number");
scanf("%d",&b);
```

The switch statement shall have a compound statement that is you have to enclose the statements in the switch in braces

```
switch(op)
{
    //...
}
```

Also it would good to include label `default` in case when the user will enter an invalid operation.

Also printf statements in the switch have invalid text and operations

```
case 2:
    printf("You have chosen the Substraction\n");
    printf("%d + %d = %d",a,b,a-b);
    // should be printf("%d - %d = %d",a,b,a-b);
    break;

case 3:
    printf("You have chosen the Multiplication\n");
    printf("%d + %d = %d",a,b,a*b);
    // should be printf("%d * %d = %d",a,b,a * b);
    break;

case 4:
    printf("You have chosen the Division\n");
    printf("%d + %d = %d",a,b,a/b);
    // should be printf("%d / %d = %d",a,b,a / b);
    break;
```

And it is better to output results of the operations as having type `long long int`

For example

```
    printf("You have chosen the Multiplication\n");
    printf("%d * %d = %lld", a, b, ( long long int )a * b);
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

you also missed a `{` after `switch`? check closely for the compiler errors. and see if you missed any of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the curly bracelet `{` opening after switch(op)

```
switch(expression) {
    case constant-expression  :
        statement(s);
        break; /* optional */

    case constant-expression  :
        statement(s);
        break; /* optional */

   default : /* Optional */
   statement(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your code more before posting. Also, you need to be more conscientious when coding, there are many error on your example (I will only talk about the `do... while` here, many people already talked about these errors :

- Missing `f`on the second `printf()`
- Missing `;` after `scanf()`
- Missing parenthesis on your `while` condition

The result is :

```
do {
    printf("choose an operation\n\n");
    printf("1 : Addition\n 2: Substraction\n 3: Multiplication\n 4: Division");
    scanf("%d",&op);
} while ((op != 1) && (op != 2) && (op != 3) && (op != 4));
```

You **must** be more rigorous with your code, especially when learning, you should take care to not take bad habits.

Comment: thank you but i still have this problems:

Comment: expected identifier  or  " ( " before " do "

Comment: @johndoe you must first rewrite your code correctly, correct spotted error and then update your post, if you do not find the solution by yourself. If you don't try to correct your code without any help, you could not progress.